# PHP code migration

Tags: php, migration

I am a fresh php developer, currently maintaining/monitoring my company php code. I am being assigned to re-write a new php function to replace the old one, However the old function is being called 24/7.

I have started writing the new function , however I always afraid that I will miss out the parameter.

Therefore, I was thinking if you guys have any advice when migrate old function to new function ? What should I be aware of.

Thanks

Comment: Same amount of parameters and same type of return? Check if functions used are not deprecated?

Comment: extra few parameters and return is basically the same but extra information return.